# How to remove subdomain from root path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I want to remove the subdomain from root path.

I tried adding `:subdomain => false` to the `root` command in `routes.rb` file without success: when I enter manually a subdomain in the URL, the subdomain stays and will not be removed.

Example:

```
my root is => lvh.me:3000
enter subdomain manually => xyz.lvh.me:3000 and hit enter then it remains the same
```

This is what I tried already in my `routes.rb` file, without success:

```
root :to => 'home#show', :subdomain => false or
root :to => 'home#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => false }, via: [:get]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this in application controller. this will work.

```
before_action :check_subdomain

def check_subdomain
  unless company_signed_in?
    if request.subdomain.present? && params[:controller] == "companies/registrations" && params[:action] == "new"
      redirect_to root_url, subdomain: false
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment on rails github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10180#issuecomment-16270920), in Rails >= 4 you need to use constraints to obtain this. Try this:

```
constraints subdomain: false do
  root to: 'home#show'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@dgilperez: your code works great, but I need to change in application controller too, Yes, I found the solution, I just updated with

```
before_action :check_subdomain

def check_subdomain
  unless company_signed_in?
    if request.subdomain.present? && params[:controller] == "companies/registrations" && params[:action] == "new"
      redirect_to root_url, subdomain: false
    end
  end
end
```